# Lookup filter on a junction object

Tags: lookup, relationships, lookup-filter

I need to make a lookup on Object A that looks up on the Contact object.

Filter Criteria:

Object A has an event attached to it. The event has a list of contacts.

How can I create a lookup filter that filters based on the Event's contacts that is attached to object a?

Shematic:

Object A Lookup ------> Event -------> Contacts on Event

Comment: How are you trying to do this right now.  Through code or standard functionality?  What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you can do this out of the box, if you take a look at the lookup filter cheatsheet [here](https://na8.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_filtered_lookups_cheatsheet.pdf), it states you can only use values directly related to the target.

> Lookup filters are administrator settings that restrict the valid
>   values and lookup dialog results for lookup, master-detail, and
>   hierarchical relationship fields. Administrators specify the
>   restrictions by configuring filter criteria that compare fields and
>   values on:
>
> • The current record (source)
>
> • The lookup object (target)
>
> • The user's record, permissions, and role
>
> • Records directly related to the target object

Comment: Would it be possible to validate that the contact on the object exists within the event instead?

Comment: You might be able to use the vlookup in the validation rule to accomplish this... http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/validating-data-based-on-fields-in-other-records